# How to install Astroneer on PC after 1.0 release?

Tags: pc, windows-10, astroneer

My son paid for the Alpha version of Astroneer. He had it on both Xbox and PC. When the full game came out, he tried to install the update on his PC, but it wouldn't update, so he uninstalled it. It updated on the Xbox. He wants it back on his PC.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Why can't he installed it on his laptop? Any error messages? Is it in his library?

Comment: Were going to need more information about why the update failed and why you can't just reinstall the game.   Is it in his game library?   Can you not find the install button?

Answer (score 4):

I recently went through the same issue with this game, and it turned out that the problem was occurring because I needed to download the latest version of Windows 10 to play it on my PC.  This is because the latest version of the game requires the October Update of Windows 10.  See below the image for all of the minimum requirements to run the game.  The first requirement is be on at least Build Number 17763, which is a build of the October Update.

Prior to installing the October Update for Windows 10, the Install button on the store page for the game would display a circle with a slash through it indicating that it could not be installed.  After the update, it let me install it from store with no issues.

To get the latest updates for Windows, search "Check For Updates" in the search feature on Windows 10.  From there, you may have to press the "Check for updates" button and then it should begin downloading the latest updates.  This may take a while, and it will require a restart of the PC once all updates have been retrieved and loaded for install.

[image: Game Reqs]

Additional information on how to install the October Update can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028685/windows-10-get-the-update).  If this still not does work, make sure you are also signed in on the laptop as the same Microsoft Account that purchased the game originally.  I've also read that signing out of the Microsoft Store and back in may also help.